$\forall x:\mathbb P(M/n\leq x\mid S=n\mu +N)\to 1$ if $N=o(n)$?
Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of iid random variables with values in $\mathbb N$ and expected value $\mu$, $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$, $M_n=\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Furthermore suppose that $N=o(n)$ and $\forall n:n\mu +N_n\in\mathbb N$. Is it correct that
$$\forall x>0:\mathbb P(M_n/n\leq x\mid S_n=n\mu +N_n)\to 1?$$
This kind of weak law of large numbers is relevant in the context of the critical density of zero range processes.
Edit: It was pointed out in the comments that there is a trivial counterexample. So I should rather ask under what additional assumptions this proposition is true.

For an arbitrary $N_n$ with $N_n=0(n)$ the conditioning event ${S_n=n\mu +N_n}$ may have probability $0$ (e.g. $X_n \equiv 1, N_n=1$).
